# How to append to string with a concatenated anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

```
var universe = true;
var string = 'hello ' + (() => {
    if (universe = true) {
        return 'universe';
    } else {
        return 'world';
    }
});
```

Why doesn't this return 'hello universe'? How can I achieve this? I am trying to dynamically build a string -- my specific use case is for creating HTML.

Comment: You also have a bug here: `if (universe = true)` -- that is an assignment statement.  You most likely mean `universe === true`

Comment: Why use a function for that in the first place? A conditional operator would seem shorter and simpler. Did you need a new scope for some reason?

Comment: This smells like a duplicate question.

Comment: `var string = "hello" + ((universe) ? "universe" : "hello");`

Comment: Think again: You want to concatenate a **string** with a **function**. What do you think is the *string representation* of a *function*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call anonymous function:

```
var universe = true;
var string = 'hello ' + (() => {
    if (universe = true) {
        return 'universe';
    } else {
        return 'world';
    }
})(); // <--- notice () here
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You are simply concatenating the *function reference* with the *string*, that will results in concatenating the ***primitive*** value of that *function object* to the target string. So in this case you have to call that function instead of concatenating it directly.

```
var universe = true;
var string = 'hello ' + (() => {
    if (universe == true) {
        return 'universe';
    } else {
        return 'world';
    }
})();
```

And a most readable version of your code would be,

```
var universe = true;
var fetchResult = () => (universe) ? 'universe' : 'world';
var string = 'hello ' + fetchResult();
```

Also note that you are *assigning* a value in *if statement* instead of *comparing* it. That, if statement will be evaluated to `true` block always since `universe = true` will always evaluated to `true`.

Comment: I recommend to use **bold** or *italic* text to express emphasis and leave `code blocks` for actual code.

Comment: @FelixKling I habituated to that. Will try to change it. :)

Comment: I appreciate how in depth you went. I now understand that I need to add another set of parenthesis at the end. What does "primitive value of the function" mean?

Answer (score 2):

More concise way

```
var universe = true;
var string = 'hello ' + (() => universe ? 'universe' : 'world')();
```

Comment: @FelixKling I agree with you, no any point, it's just shorter version of the OP's function, *less code - less bugs*.
OP has one error in the `if` statement